# Python logging: No output from custom logger

Tags: python-3.x, logging

Using tutorial: https://realpython.com/python-logging/ ,
I have following script, only containing:

```
import logging

# Create a custom logger
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

# Create handlers
c_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
f_handler = logging.FileHandler('file.log')
c_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
f_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

# Create formatters and add it to handlers
c_format = logging.Formatter('%(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
f_format = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
c_handler.setFormatter(c_format)
f_handler.setFormatter(f_format)

# Add handlers to the logger
logger.addHandler(c_handler)
logger.addHandler(f_handler)

logger.debug('I am a debug msg')
logger.info('I am an info msg')
```

Which should write strings both to the console and to a file ('file.log').
The file is created, bot has no content. And there is no output to the console either.
Any ideas what could cause this, or what is missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to set the verbose level for the logger itself:

```
import logging

# Create a custom logger
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG) # The logger still needs its verbose level

# Create handlers
c_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
f_handler = logging.FileHandler('file.log')
c_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
f_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

# Create formatters and add it to handlers
c_format = logging.Formatter('%(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
f_format = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
c_handler.setFormatter(c_format)
f_handler.setFormatter(f_format)

# Add handlers to the logger
logger.addHandler(c_handler)
logger.addHandler(f_handler)

logger.debug('I am a debug msg')
logger.info('I am an info msg')
```

Also I would recommend blocking your code in terms of each handler, not similar syntax:

```
import logging

# Create a custom logger
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

# Streaming Handler
c_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
c_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
c_format = logging.Formatter('%(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
c_handler.setFormatter(c_format)
logger.addHandler(c_handler)

# File Handler
f_handler = logging.FileHandler('file.log')
f_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
f_format = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
f_handler.setFormatter(f_format)
logger.addHandler(f_handler)

logger.debug('I am a debug msg')
logger.info('I am an info msg')
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, now everything works, and your suggestion so seperate the handlers improves readability.